# Using multiple XPATHS in SELECt

Tags: xml, postgresql, select, xpath, insert

I am having difficulty with my SQL it is PLPGSQL 
I am trying to select some XML from an XML column, where the contents of a node contain a value and appears in a different tablet and the value contains a date.

It seems you cannot hove more than one XPATH in a statement as when I delete any two of the AND lines, the statement is successful.

```
INSERT INTO waterData_ToSend(wbreference, wbcreation, wb_id, list)
SELECT wbreference, wbcreation, wb_id, ((xpath('/Bottle/Water/text()', XMLdetails))[1])::text
FROM "dbWaterDescricum".tbl_deliverItems
WHERE clientel = 314 
AND strpos(((xpath('/Bottle/Water/text()', XMLdetails))[1])::text ,'_WB_') > 0
AND strpos(((xpath('/Bottle/Water/text()', XMLdetails))[1])::text , CURRENT_DATE - 7) > 0
AND CAST(xpath('/Bottle/Water/text()', XMLdetails) as text) IN (SELECT list FROM bottle_list)
LIMIT 15;
```

The error I get when i dont do commenting of the AND is

```
ERROR:  could not parse XML document
DETAIL:  line 1: Namespace prefix xmlns on texthelpns is not defined
```